# Compare a value from a return function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code where the return plano;* gives me what I want.

```
userInfoConst() async {
    try {
      var uid = await AuthenticationProvider().getUserId();
      ApiProvider apiProvider = ApiProvider();
      final usuarioModel =
          await apiProvider.getRequest('usuarios/$uid');
      UsuarioModel model = UsuarioModel.fromJson(usuarioModel.data);
      var plano =  model.plano;
      print(plano);
      return plano;
  }
```

And I want to compare the value in the if conditional but the values don't match, they are not being "compared" and never executes the code bellow. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst() == 'FREE') {
      _banner
        ..load()
        ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
    }
```

Comment: Change `ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst() == 'FREE'` to `(await ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst()) == 'FREE'`.

Comment: my if is inside of the Widget build(), so I can't use await

Comment: @augustofrancisco Then use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly compare value over-there because your function is async.

You can call that function on initState and then you can load your advertisement.

I hope following example clear your idea.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Widget _widget = Container();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    buildWidget();
  }

  Future<bool> hi() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    return true;
  }

  buildWidget() {
    hi().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value) {
          _widget = Text("hello");
        } else {
          _widget = Text("hi");
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(child: _widget),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In Your case:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    buildWidget();
  }

  buildWidget() {
    ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value == "FREE") {
         _banner
        ..load()
        ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
        } 
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand now but I'm still not able to solve my problem...

Comment: @augustofrancisco i added some more code. what you can do in your case. i hope now you will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: dude, you saved my life! Thank you so much!!